# Sets of primes and congruences

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $s$ be a positive integer, and let $\mathcal{P}$ be a set of primes having cardinality equal to $s$. For a partition
$$\displaystyle \mathcal{Q}_1 \cup \mathcal{Q}_2 \cup \mathcal{Q}_3 = \mathcal{P}$$

of $\mathcal{P}$, put

$$\displaystyle q_i = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{Q}_i} p.$$

We say that the partition $\{\mathcal{Q}_1, \mathcal{Q}_2, \mathcal{Q}_3\}$ is *good* if one has for any $\{i,j,k\} = \{1,2,3\}$ that

$$\displaystyle q_i \equiv (-1)^j q_j  \pmod{q_k}.$$

For a given finite set of $\mathcal{P}$ of primes, put $r(\mathcal{P})$ for the number of good partitions of $\mathcal{P}$. My question concerns the behaviour of the function

$$\displaystyle f(s) = \max_{|\mathcal{P}| = s} r(\mathcal{P}).$$

In particular, what are some lower bounds for $f(s)$? Clearly, we have $f(s) \leq 3^s$.

Further, what are the properties of sets $\mathcal{P}$ which achieves large values of $r(\mathcal{P})$?

Comment: When you say 'for any $\{i,j,k\}=\{1,2,3\}$' do you mean 'all' or 'some'? My usual reading would be the former, but if that's the case then unless I'm missing something.there can't be any good partitions of a set of primes; WLOG take $q_1\lt q_2\lt q_3$; then saying $q_1\equiv q_2\pmod q_3$ is the same as saying $q_1=q_2$, contradiction.

Comment: I added a twist factor that I think removes this issue. For example, if $m_1, m_2, m_3$ are three coprime positive square-free integers satisfying $m_1 - m_2 + m_3 = 0$ then the set of prime divisors of $m_1 m_2 m_3$ has a non-trivial good partition.